# PouchDB returning wrong image attachment type

Tags: javascript, electron, blob, pouchdb

I'm trying to get PouchDB to return a small image attachment.  When I upload the image through Fauxton, my app successfully returns a Blob with `type: 'image/svg+xml'` that renders correctly in my `<img>` element (using `URL.createObjectURL`).

However, if I have the user upload an image, and then put the file Blob to my remote Pouch database, I have problems.  In this case, `PouchDB.getAttachment()` now returns a Blob with `type: 'application/octet-stream'` instead of `'image/svg+xml'`, despite having uploaded it with the correct `content_type`.  This image does not render, giving me a generic browser img placeholder.

Why could this be occurring?

**Step 1** Here is how I retrieve the image from the user:

```
var image = new Blob([fs.readFileSync(fileLocation, 'utf-8')], {
   type: 'image/svg+xml'
})
```

**Step 2** Here is how I put my document (and attachment) to PouchDB:

```
var doc = await PouchDB.get(docID, {attachments: true})
doc._attachments = {
    'logo.svg': {
        content_type: 'image/svg+xml',
        data: image
    }
}
await PouchDB.put(doc)
```

Comment: how do you put your attachment to the db?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post to answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got 2 problems with reading your file. First is that you can't treat binary data as UTF8 (may not be a real problem with SVG file, but with other images surely is), and the second one is that you have to base64 encode it.

There are many different approaches to base64 encode a blob, but the easiest solution would be to change the method of putting it from `put` to `putAttachment`. Something like this:

HTML:

```
...
<input type="file" id="inputFile">
...
```

JS:

```
...
var inputFile = document.querySelector('#inputFile');
var file = inputFile.files[0];
db.putAttachment('mydoc', 'myfile', file, file.type).then(...)
...
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.  Now for some reason I'm getting an update conflict when using `putAttachment` instead of a standard `put()`.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to change doc._rev when updateing... `db.putAttachment('mydoc', 'myfile', rev_id, file, file.type)`